# Trying to find javascript element's position on screen....Not working properly on webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code i'm using right now. On webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari Specifically) if the page is scrolled, it doesn't take into account the amount that page has been scrolled. I need help redesigning the function to work for Webkit browsers. And I don't want to be loading up jQuery as this will be used on a web widget and I need to keep the file size down. Thanks guys!

```
function __getIEVersion() {
    var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null)
            rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
    }
    return rv;
}

function __getOperaVersion() {
    var rv = 0; // Default value
    if (window.opera) {
        var sver = window.opera.version();
        rv = parseFloat(sver);
    }
    return rv;
}

var __userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
var __isIE =  navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE/) != null;
var __IEVersion = __getIEVersion();
var __isIENew = __isIE && __IEVersion >= 8;
var __isIEOld = __isIE && !__isIENew;

var __isFireFox = __userAgent.match(/firefox/i) != null;
var __isFireFoxOld = __isFireFox && ((__userAgent.match(/firefox\/2./i) != null) || 
    (__userAgent.match(/firefox\/1./i) != null));
var __isFireFoxNew = __isFireFox && !__isFireFoxOld;

var __isWebKit =  navigator.appVersion.match(/WebKit/) != null;
var __isChrome =  navigator.appVersion.match(/Chrome/) != null;
var __isOpera =  window.opera != null;
var __operaVersion = __getOperaVersion();
var __isOperaOld = __isOpera && (__operaVersion < 10);

function __parseBorderWidth(width) {
    var res = 0;
    if (typeof(width) == "string" && width != null && width != "" ) {
        var p = width.indexOf("px");
        if (p >= 0) {
            res = parseInt(width.substring(0, p));
        }
        else {
            //do not know how to calculate other values 
        //(such as 0.5em or 0.1cm) correctly now
            //so just set the width to 1 pixel
            res = 1; 
        }
    }
    return res;
}

//returns border width for some element
function __getBorderWidth(element) {
    var res = new Object();
    res.left = 0; res.top = 0; res.right = 0; res.bottom = 0;
    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        //for Firefox
        var elStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);
        res.left = parseInt(elStyle.borderLeftWidth.slice(0, -2));  
        res.top = parseInt(elStyle.borderTopWidth.slice(0, -2));  
        res.right = parseInt(elStyle.borderRightWidth.slice(0, -2));  
        res.bottom = parseInt(elStyle.borderBottomWidth.slice(0, -2));  
    }
    else {
        //for other browsers
        res.left = __parseBorderWidth(element.style.borderLeftWidth);
        res.top = __parseBorderWidth(element.style.borderTopWidth);
        res.right = __parseBorderWidth(element.style.borderRightWidth);
        res.bottom = __parseBorderWidth(element.style.borderBottomWidth);
    }

    return res;
}

//returns the absolute position of some element within document
function getElementAbsolutePos(element) {
    var res = new Object();
    res.x = 0; res.y = 0;
    if (element !== null) { 
        if (element.getBoundingClientRect) {
            var viewportElement = document.documentElement;  
            var box = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            var scrollLeft = viewportElement.scrollLeft;
            var scrollTop = viewportElement.scrollTop;

            res.x = box.left + scrollLeft;
            res.y = box.top + scrollTop;

        }
        else { //for old browsers
            res.x = element.offsetLeft;
            res.y = element.offsetTop;

            var parentNode = element.parentNode;
            var borderWidth = null;

            while (offsetParent != null) {
                res.x += offsetParent.offsetLeft;
                res.y += offsetParent.offsetTop;

                var parentTagName = 
                    offsetParent.tagName.toLowerCase(); 

                if ((__isIEOld && parentTagName != "table") || 
                    ((__isFireFoxNew || __isChrome) && 
                        parentTagName == "td")) {           
                    borderWidth = kGetBorderWidth
                            (offsetParent);
                    res.x += borderWidth.left;
                    res.y += borderWidth.top;
                }

                if (offsetParent != document.body && 
                offsetParent != document.documentElement) {
                    res.x -= offsetParent.scrollLeft;
                    res.y -= offsetParent.scrollTop;
                }


                //next lines are necessary to fix the problem 
                //with offsetParent
                if (!__isIE && !__isOperaOld || __isIENew) {
                    while (offsetParent != parentNode && 
                        parentNode !== null) {
                        res.x -= parentNode.scrollLeft;
                        res.y -= parentNode.scrollTop;
                        if (__isFireFoxOld || __isWebKit) 
                        {
                            borderWidth = 
                             kGetBorderWidth(parentNode);
                            res.x += borderWidth.left;
                            res.y += borderWidth.top;
                        }
                        parentNode = parentNode.parentNode;
                    }    
                }

                parentNode = offsetParent.parentNode;
                offsetParent = offsetParent.offsetParent;
            }
        }
    }

    var scrOfX = 0, scrOfY = 0;
    if( typeof( window.pageYOffset ) == 'number' ) {
        //Netscape compliant
        scrOfY = window.pageYOffset;
        scrOfX = window.pageXOffset;
    } else if( document.body && ( document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop ) ) {
        //DOM compliant
        scrOfY = document.body.scrollTop;
        scrOfX = document.body.scrollLeft;
    } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop ) ) {
        //IE6 standards compliant mode
        scrOfY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        scrOfX = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    }


    return res;
}
```

Comment: Why are you calculating scrOfX/Y at the end of the function? Shouldn't you calculate them first, and then use them as necessary?

Comment: Doesn't matter where I put it, same problem.

Comment: I'm concerned that when you use `getBoundingClientRect()` you assume that you can always read the scrollX/Y in the same way, which I'm not sure is true.

Comment: So how would I go fixing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>     if (element.getBoundingClientRect) {
>         var viewportElement = document.documentElement;  
>         var box = element.getBoundingClientRect();
>         var scrollLeft = viewportElement.scrollLeft;
>         var scrollTop = viewportElement.scrollTop;
>
>         res.x = box.left + scrollLeft;
>         res.y = box.top + scrollTop;
>
>     }
> ```

I'm concerned that this code block only uses one way of attempting to detect the scroll position. I would move the bottom block of code to the top of the function and use scrOfX/Y instead of scrollLeft and scrollTop.